# NDepend: Listing the attributes attached to a method, is it possible?

Tags: c#, ndepend, cqlinq

I am trying to use NDepend and its Linq based query language to generate some reports about the code's current state. I want to label some of my methods and classes with predefined "tags", for example the methods labeled with tag "Database" contains database specific code, the ones labeled with tag "Algorithm_X" contains specific logic related to an algorithm "X". We think that such a tagging procedure will lead to a more straightforward documentation generation process.

I wonder whether NDepend provides a mechanism which facilitates such a process. I am thinking of using C# Attributes to generate such custom tags and then labeling methods with appropriate attributes which corresponds to "tagging" them. I am well aware of the ".HasAttribute" method of CQLinq and actively using it. But this tagging procedure needs a way to list or enumerate all Attributes attached to a method and I failed to realize it using NDepend until now.

My question is;  is there a way to implement that (listing all attributes of a method) in NDepend? If not, is there another way in NDepend which would facilitate such a tagging procedure? I may implement this using Reflections by writing custom C# code, but I want to be sure that I am out of options with NDepend at this state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually lists attributes tagging a method with [NDepend LINQ code querying (CQLINQ)](http://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL) but it is not straightforward nor fast. We plan to improve attributes support in the NDepend code model, it has been asked on the [NDepend User Voice](http://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/5544407-being-able-to-read-attribute-property-values).

So the following query works but it can take a few second on a large code base (which is slow for NDepend where typically queries are executed in a few milliseconds):

```
let typesAttributes = Types.Where(t => t.IsAttributeClass)
from m in Methods
let mAttributes = typesAttributes.Where(t => m.HasAttribute(t)).ToArray()
where mAttributes .Length > 0
select new { m, mAttributes }
```

The optimization below will make it run twice faster in general.

```
let typesAttributes = Types.Where(t => t.IsAttributeClass)
from m in Types.UsingAny(typesAttributes).ChildMethods()
let mAttributes = typesAttributes.Where(t => m.HasAttribute(t)).ToArray()
where mAttributes .Length > 0
select new { m, mAttributes }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Going one step further, is it possible to obtain Attribute parameters as well? For example if I have a Attribute `[TagAttribute("Class Info")]
class MyClass 
{
}` defined on my class, is it possible to obtain the string "Class Info" somehow with using CqLinq?

Comment: Not yet possible, this is the NDepend User Voices linked in the response, don't hesitate to vote for it and comment.  http://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/5544407-being-able-to-read-attribute-property-values